# Multiple operatores in one if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

I made the following statement:

```js
if (command !== "define" || (command !== "add") || (command !== "remove")) throw "ERROR 1";
```

It's inside a try if statement.
I want it so that if the command is not "define", "add" or "remove" it throws the error.
However, even if I do something like

/money define, it still throws the error.
Separated, it would look like this:

```js
if (command !== "define") throw "ERROR 1";
if (command !== "add") throw "ERROR 2";
if (command !== "remove") throw "ERROR 3";
```

Full code:

```js
mp.events.addCommand('dinheiro', (player, _, command, amount, targetPlayer) => {
    var isSuccess = true;
    try {
        if (command !== "definir" || (command !== "adicionar") || (command !== "retirar")) throw "ERORR 1";
    }
    catch (err) {
        isSuccess = false;
    }
    if (isSuccess) {
      //code
    }
```

I removed unnecessary parts, but I always get throw the ERROR 1, so the problem is most probably in the if statement.

Comment: If it *is* equal to one of the strings, then it is also *not* equal to the other two. Thus the statement always evaluates to `true`.

Comment: How so? I want it to check string by string if it's equal or not. I can't do it in one if?

Comment: You can, but you want `&&` not `||`

Comment: That's it. Thanks. I always read that as:
If not this, and not this, and not this, then

Comment: `if( !["define", "add", "remove"].includes(command) ) throw "ERORR";`

Answer (score 2):

`if (command !== "define" && (command !== "add") && (command !== "remove")) throw "ERROR 1";`

The or operator (`||`) will return true as soon as one of the operands evaluates to true so e.g. if the command is "add" the first clause is true because command is not "define".